# Accelereated Mobile Page - dynamic pages

Tags: amp-html

I am quite impressed by the new AMP and would like to implement it on my mobile site. Most of the content on my mobile site is dynamic meaning based on the login user it will fetch the data from different backend services like mysql and sphinx and it will render the results.

Can I use AMP for my mobile site. After doing some search on Google I found that people are recommending it for static pages. Also how the CDN caching technique works for a dynamic pages in AMP.

Comment: Show what you have done so far

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `amp-list` component to embed user specific dynamic content ([docs](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-list/amp-list.md), [sample](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-list/)). The name `amp-list` is a bit misleading, as you can use it for single items as well. This will also work if your AMP is loaded via a cache.

The other possibility is to use an [iframe](https://ampbyexample.com/advanced/how_to_create_interactive_amp_pages/).

Answer (score 0):

I was also wondering how the cache works for dynamic pages.I found an issue on the AMP Github that basically explains that the Google Cache is respecting the Cache-control max-age attributes in the http header to evaluate when the cache has to be updated. The only thing that doesn't work is setting it to 0.

But it looks like they are working on a solution to clean the cache programmatically.

Here is the AMP GitHub relevant page:
https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/1901

Answer (score -2):

You can use AMP for dynamic sites. As we are using AMP on a WordPress website using AMP plugin i.e. a dynamic website.

You need to head to official site and follow getting started guide: https://www.ampproject.org

I add few points I have learned so far creating few AMP pages and templates so far.

As you have own custom website you need to implement and create AMP pages or AMP template yourself with two important points to consider:

1. Your normal page will have a link in the header specifying that it has AMP version of the page available with following tag:

   `<link rel="amphtml" href="exact-url-to-you-amp-version-of-this-page" />`
2. Then you will create AMP version of that page which has similar link with rel=canonical so to avoid duplicate penality i.e. AMP version will have following link:

   `<link rel="canonical" href="exact-url-to-your-original-non-amp-page" />`

That sets the stage. Now the AMP page need to adhere to very strict format i.e. you are not allowed to use stylesheets or script or img tags.  https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-html-format.md#html-tags

You can use this basic template to get started as there are few other tags you need to have in the header like AMP symbol in HTML tag in the page to declare it is AMP page. Then you build your dynamic content parts on this page following all rules i.e img tags use amp-img tags , no iframe, no inline style on html tags.. No external stylesheet.. i.e. inline css styles rules etc.
https://www.ampproject.org/docs/get_started/create/basic_markup.html

Also you may validate the AMP pages you create by adding #development=1 to the URLs and seeing for any errors in Chrome Console. More info here:
https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/validate.html

Comment: Do you serve different content to users based on their login? OP is asking about showing different versions of the same page depending on who is looking at it, which is not the same as creating content via Wordpress and having new pages appear with AMP backing pages.